# Bug in jQuery :not selector?

Tags: jquery

Given [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8zDu/10/), can anyone see why it is behaving this way? If you look in the console, you will see the element IDs and their tag name listed under either :not method or .not method. Notice how, logically, the statements which select the elements should result in the same elements? Well for some reason :not is only returning 2 elements but .not is returning 11 (the correct number by my reckoning).

Can someone either reassure me that my logic is correct and there is actually a bug here or tell me what I am doing wrong in the first statement?

Edit: Code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<input id="TITLE" class="reginput" name="TITLE" type="TEXT" size="15" maxlength="15" value="test">
<input id="FIRSTNAME" class="reginput" name="FIRSTNAME" type="TEXT" size="30" maxlength="50" value="test">
<input id="SURNAME" class="reginput" name="SURNAME" type="TEXT" size="30" maxlength="80" value="test">
<input id="EMPNO" class="reginput" name="EMPNO" type="TEXT" size="30" maxlength="50" value="">
<select name="day_DOB" id="day_DOB" class="feday"><option value="0">Day</option></select>
<select name="month_DOB" id="month_DOB" onblur="dodatecheck_data_DOB(this,document.data.day_DOB,document.data.year_DOB,'MONTH');" class="femonth"><option value="0" selected="">Month</option></select>
<select name="year_DOB" id="year_DOB" onblur="dodatecheck_data_DOB(document.data.month_DOB,document.data.day_DOB,this,'YEAR');" class="feyear"><option value="0">Year</option></select>
<input class="reginput" id="HOMEPHONENO" maxlength="50" type="TEXT" name="HOMEPHONENO" size="15" value="">
<input class="reginput" id="WORKPHONENO" maxlength="50" type="TEXT" name="WORKPHONENO" size="15" value="">
<input class="reginput" id="MOBILEPHONENO" maxlength="50" type="TEXT" name="MOBILEPHONENO" size="15" value="">
<input id="JOBTITLE" class="reginput" name="JOBTITLE" type="TEXT" size="30" maxlength="100" value="">
<input id="COMPANYNAME" class="reginput" name="COMPANYNAME" type="TEXT" size="30" maxlength="100" value="">
<select id="CandGeneralField5" name="CandGeneralField5" class="reginput"><option value="0">&lt; Please select &gt;</option><option value="12">Female</option><option value="11">Male</option><option value="13">Prefer not to disclose</option></select>​
```

jQuery (using 1.7.2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(":not method");
    $elems = $("input[type=text][id], select[id]:not(select#month_DOB, select#year_DOB), textarea[id], tr input[type=submit][id]");
    $elems.each(function() {
            console.log("\t" + $(this).attr("id") + " - " + this.nodeName.toLowerCase());
    });
    console.log("\tCount: " + $elems.length);    
    console.log(".not method");
    $elems = $("input[type=text][id], select[id], textarea[id], tr input[type=submit][id]")
      .not("select#month_DOB, select#year_DOB");
      $elems.each(function() {
            console.log("\t" + $(this).attr("id") + " - " + this.nodeName.toLowerCase());
      });          
    console.log("\tCount: " + $elems.length);    
});​
```

Edit: Just to clarify, my logic is that it should select the following in both cases:

- text inputs which have an id;
- selects which have an id but not select#month_DOB or select#year_DOB;
- textareas which have an id;
- inputs of type submit which have an id and are within a tr.

PS I know the markup is rubbish - it is output by the core code of the produce I work on and there is nothing I can do about it.. theres oh so many things I would change if I could :)

Comment: Don't give us the whole code like this. Just reduce your problem to a small piece of code and __paste it__ in your question (because if JSFiddle goes down, in one year, no body will see the code).

Comment: To validate a bug split your example into smaller pieces of code! Please don't bring up an extended example but only a example piece of code.

Comment: Sorry, it was narrowed down to well under a 10th of what it was originally! It's just dreadful! I've updated the link to a new JSFiddle and added the code above.

Comment: This has now been reported on the jQuery forums at https://forum.jquery.com/topic/not-selector-not-working-as-expected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like :not will not take chained selectors, like `:not(#id1, #id2)`. Instead you need to do `:not(#id1):not(#id2)`.

Here's a modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/EM5FP/

As for *why* it won't work, that may be a question best left to the jQuery devs.

Comment: hmm yeah that is a good point.. according to http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ using :not(div,a) *should* work.

Answer (score 1):

If you put `select[id]:not(select#month_DOB, select#year_DOB)` to the first position it works:

```
$elems = $("span#volumemaindetails")
  .find("select[id]:not(select#month_DOB, select#year_DOB), input[type=text][id], textarea[id], tr input[type=submit][id]");
```

Also see [the updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/n8zDu/11/). Please don't ask me why :-)

=== UPDATE ===

Maybe the following can explain @jackwanders answer:

From the w3c css3 defintion for [negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

> The **negation pseudo-class**, **:not(X)**, is a functional notation taking a **simple selector** (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument.

A [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) is defined by:

> A simple selector is **either** a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

I would interpret the fact that not a comma is allowed in the selector (group of selectors) or the combination of a type and id selector.

jQuery *not()* method allows probably more than is allowed by CSS3.
( They will call it a feature ;-) )

Comment: Thanks scessor. I wouldn't have thought the order of selectors would make a difference so hadn't tried it. Seems there may be a couple of 'bugs' here in that case (altho some may refer to them as 'features').

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'd say they should either remove the ',' functionality from the :not selector and update the page to say so, or they should fix it so it works as we would expect (based on the :not documentation). I've been driven mad by this several times now - finally found out what was going on :).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in new versions of jQuery.

It works fine in jQuery 1.4.4

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V7XwJ/1/)

Comment: Ah yes, 1.5.2 it was broken in. Thanks for pointing this out. I've created a post on the jQuery forums with a pointer to this question - hopefully one of their devs will get involved and pick up all the findings from here to locate the issue.

Comment: Congrats for finding a bug :) I always dream of one ;)

Comment: Its only too common with me - I'm not allowed to edit the core code of the product I work on, only customise it with CSS / HTML / jQuery (and ASP to some extent). I'm notorious for finding bugs and really really wind support up on a weekly basis :)